# Meaning of 途方もなくみすばらしい小屋

Tags: grammar, adjectives, adverbs

> その岩のてっぺんに、**途方もなくみすばらしい小屋**がちょこんと乗っている
> A preposterous, splendid shed is perched on top of that rock. (my literal TL)
> Perched on top of the rock was the most miserable little shack you could imagine. (original text)

My first confusion is the み in 途方もなくみ. I thought that adding み to an adjective turned it into a noun. Why would I want a noun in this position? If 途方もない is modifying すばらしい then why not just keep the く ending? If it's modifying 小屋 then why not just keep the い ending?

My second confusion is with すばらしい. I thought this was a positive sounding word (splendid, wonderful etc). It doesn't seem to have any place in this description of misery.

Comment: Just a misreading and lack of sleep. Please vote to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've segmented the words wrongly — it is (途方もなく)(みすぼらしい)(小屋). Adding み to the *stem* of an adjective forms an abstract noun, but that's not what's happening here.

And it's worth confirming but is it not [みすぼらしい](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%BF%E3%81%99%E3%81%BC%E3%82%89%E3%81%97%E3%81%84-638121#:%7E:text=%E3%80%98%E5%BD%A2%E5%8F%A3%E3%80%99%20%E3%81%BF%E3%81%99%E3%81%BC%E3%82%89%20%E3%81%97,%E8%B2%A7%E3%81%97%E3%81%92%E3%81%A7%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B%E3%80%82)? The meaning "shabby" would fit in perfectly.

Comment: Argh!. Yes I misread it. It is ぼ.